# GWT: getting 404 in GWTTestCase when trying to make an Ajax call

Tags: gwt, junit, gwttestcase

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I'm trying to write a test case where I make an Ajax call, but I'm getting a 404.  Here is how I define the service in my .gwt.xml file ...

```
<module>
  <!-- Inherit our applications main module.                      -->
  <inherits name='com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlus' />

  <!-- Specify the path to any remote services.                   -->
  <servlet path="/xmlhelperservice" class="com.myco.clearing.product.server.XmlHelperServiceImpl" />

</module>
```

Here is how the interface that the service implements ...

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath( "xmlhelperservice" )
public interface XmlHelperService extends RemoteService {

    Node getNode(final String fileName) throws IOException;

}
```

but in my test class (that extends GWTTestCase), I'm getting a 404 when trying to invoke the service ...

```
public void testDocument() throws Exception {
    xmlHelperService = GWT.create(XmlHelperService.class);
    xmlHelperService.getNode("doc.xml", new AsyncCallback<Node>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Node node) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            caught.printStackTrace(System.err);
            fail(caught.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

What is the right way to define/invoke my service to avoid the 404?  Stack trace below.  Thanks, - Dave

```
[WARN] 404 - POST /com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlusJUnit.JUnit/xmlhelperservice (10.40.70.197) 1450 bytes
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2><pre>NOT_FOUND</pre>
<p>RequestURI=/com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlusJUnit.JUnit/xmlhelperservice</p><p><i><small><a href="http://jetty.mortbay.org/">Powered by Jetty://</a></small></i></p><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>

at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:209)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:220)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you have overlooked this in your web.xml file.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>XmlHelperServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myco.clearing.product.server.XmlHelperServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XmlHelperServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/com.myco.clearing.product.ProductPlus/xmlhelperservice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also see [common pitfalls](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRemoteProcedureCalls) in this documentation.